# How to attach a specific PDF to an email in PHP?

Tags: php, email, pdf

Using FPDF, I render a form contents into PDF form and save them to a folder.

Now, I'd like to create a `.php` file that sends an email to users with the PDF attached.

How do I ensure that the PDF being pulled from the folder and being attached to outgoing email is for that specific client?

```
require_once($dir.'SpecificUser.pdf');
$pdf_html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

the whole process is:

- list all or our users/members in the browser next to their names are
- options to view their PDF browser OR email them the PDF

I'm not sure how to tie that email to client`enter code here` option/button to their specific saved PDF.

Comment: You will need a library to accomplish this, or a lot more code since the built in mail system in php is awful. You can try PHPMailer or Pear Mail. both allow sending attachments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a PDF file in a string, use `file_get_contents()` rather than the `ob_` function you've suggested.

Other than that, to attach a client-specific PDF to your email, do this:

- Generate the PDF
- Save it in a temporary folder
- Attach it to the email object using a library method
- Delete the PDF (or save it for future reference if that is better for you)

As per the comments, don't use `mail()` - SMTP mail sending is *hard* to do correctly. Either use a proper library like SwiftMailer, or use a third-party email system like MailChimp.

Comment: Thanks for the message -- didn't realize I could use MailChimp in this situation -- I'll look into it

Comment: Yes, they have an API, which should make this really easy. (MailChimp is just one example, it would be advisable to try several. There's many a blog post on the web that compares a few popular ones).